# How to include Android theme from another project

Tags: android, resources, greendroid

I'm a beginner in Android development (and in Java too).
I'm trying to compile the Financisto open source project which uses GreenDroid.
I've managed to compile GreenDroid itself, but have failed to compile Financisto.
When I try to "compile" Financisto resources like that:

```
aapt.exe package -m -J f:\fin\src -M f:\fin\AndroidManifest.xml -A assets 
         -S f:\fin\res -I c:\android-sdk\platforms\adroid-8\android.jar
```

But aapt throws the next error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
'@style/Theme.GreenDroid').
```

As I understand it's because AndroidManifest contains

```
<manifest ...>
  <aplication android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenDroid" ...
```

Theme.GreenDroid defined in GreenDroid/res/values/gd_themes.xml
I've tried to google it but didn't manage to find an answer: how I shoud make this style from GreenDroid visible from Financisto?

It seems author of Financisto uses IntilliJ & Mac, but I want to compile it from console & Win7, so asking an author about how to compile it not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the GreenDroid project, as a reference from your existing project.

In eclipse, right-mouse click on your project, then Properties>Java Build Path then add the GreenDroid to the Project tab.

Good luck

Comment: "but I want to compile it from console & Win7"